# How to match regex for TLD?

Tags: regex

I know there are lot of regex for the purpose, but in my case the regex i want to write is one that matches following payload

```
 ...............sssfdf.makememad.com......
........makemadcom.....
dfdfddd   makeme.ru.......
also ...makeme.net.......
```

I just want to match anything with following

```
.ru
.net
.com
```

And due to some limitations of the software in which im using the regex it won't allow to do this

```
\.
```

so any regex which skips this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you escape a period then in your engine then, what engine are you using? Also that looks like the text dump from a hex editor. Are all those periods really periods or are they really unprintable text from a hex editor. Please provide more detail about how you are trying to do what you want to do. I would put money that whatever language you are using uses `\ ` as a escape character so you need to escape the escape via something like `"\\."`

Comment: the engine works fine on other traffic but one particular application traffic e.g dns it won't work. Its closed system SIEM solution. The engine uses java regex

Comment: Well java supports [escaping metacharaters with a slash](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a character class since you don't need to escape:

```
[.](ru|net|com)
```